# how to authenticate to ldap server using mail id instead of user name

Tags: ldap

I have a created a ldap server . I registered some users in that server. For now i am able to login through server using username and password of users from my mac system.But now i want to login through server using mail id and password of users instead of username and password.How to change this setting in mappings of ldap in mac.

Comment: So you have an LDAP-Server as authentication-backend for MacOS-machines. When a user logs into a MacOS-machine the authentication is drone by the LDAP-backend. For that to work you have either setup an Apple OpenDirectory (would work right out of the box) or you have manually tweaked a lot of settings to get that to work. Which setup do you use? In both cases it would involve manual changes to the attribute-mapping but it would be helpful to know which setup you are using.

Comment: Actually i am using Directory Utility app in my mac to do all the settings. but here i am not able to trace what to map.so that i will be able to access my account by giving mail and password as credentials. @heiglandreas

Comment: Sorry to ask further: Which MacOS? 10.9? The DirectoryUtility in the new Server.app creates an OpenDirectory AFAIK

Comment: Sorry for late reply.I am using 10.9.

Comment: Shameless plug months later (but still relevant): If you want to whip together your own LDAP server with whatever mapping you want, you could start with godap: https://github.com/bradleypeabody/godap Not necessarily the simplest solution, but you could certainly solve the problem of allowing 'user@example.com' and 'user' to operate the same way for bind operations, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go through this link https://help.apple.com/advancedserveradmin/mac/10.7/#apdB5DE1FD6-4D51-4C20-BB66-982DB85DF258. it helped me a lot. we have to give DN as mail=mailaddress,OU=users,dc=example,dc=com.
and password whatever we configured during server configuration.

Comment: This will require you to have the mail address twice. Once in the mail-section and once as CN.

Answer (score 0):

I'd add a new Mapping-File to the DirectoryServices as stated in http://support.apple.com/kb/PH9293?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US. That way you can map not only the `UID` or the `CN` for logging into the machine but also the email-address. That way you will only have to store the email-address in the corresponding field that is also used by the mail server and the possibility that one time something gets mixed up due to incomplete changes is reduced.

On the other hand it might be a lengthy process to get everything right

**Update:** I've just written a blog-post about mapping LDAP-Attributes to DirectoryService-Attributes. It might be helpfull here: http://andreas.heigl.org/2014/06/05/change-opendirectory-mappings/

Comment: Can you please explain your mapping in more detailed way

Comment: I'm currently doing a blog-post about it as it's a rather complex process. I hope to finish that one this evening. I'll report back and extend my answer as soon as I'm through.

Comment: want to know more about this issue, can you please update here       @heiglandreas

Comment: Just updated. Added link to a blogpost about mapping attributes. More to come